# Current status is in root component respect module child in lazy loading router in Angular

Tags: angular, state, router

I have this code in my router config

```
path: 'printing-documents',
    component: PrintingDocumentsContentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PrintingDocumentsHomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: PrintingDocumentsNewComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: PrintingDocumentsEditComponent,
      },
    ],
```

and in my `PrintingDocumentsContentComponent` i have this code html

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    <a class="btn btn-light lamb-button" (click)="onBack()">
      <span class="fa fa-undo lamb-icon" > </span>
    </a>
    {{ titleContainer }}
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

i need is that when route is `http://localhost:4200/#/lamb/accounting/configuration/printing-documents` the button **back()**this hidden. but when is `http://localhost:4200/#/lamb/accounting/configuration/printing-documents/new` or `http://localhost:4200/#/lamb/accounting/configuration/printing-documents/15` the button is show.

I know I must do something in the method `ngOnInit ()` of the `PrintingDocumentsContentComponent` with the dependencies`ActivatedRoute` or `Router` but I do not know what.

i will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking last segment of current route.You need to import ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment and use within your component.

> In your PrintingDocumentsContentComponent.component.ts add below code

```
import { ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

let flag:boolean=false;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {

    const url: UrlSegment[] = this.route.snapshot.url;

    if(url[0].path=='printing-documents'){
      this.flag = true
    }
     else {
      this.flag = false
     }
```

> In PrintingDocumentsContentComponent.component.html

```
<a class="btn btn-light lamb-button" *ngIf="!flag" (click)="onBack()">
    <span class="fa fa-undo lamb-icon" ></span>
  </a>
```

Comment: Thank you. but this only runs once. I think that I would need this action to be associated with an **Observable** so that every time that I navigate with the routerLink I will run that script again